# Nuget packages without Open Package Conventions enforced

Tags: nuget-package, octopus-deploy, nuget-spec

Im building some nuget packages on our build server and have run into a problem.
I have to use nuget pack xxx.csproj to get replacement tokens to work with my nuspec file which is allright.
But when I do the nuget pack on the csproj a lot of "noise" is added to the package in form of folders etc from Open Package Convention.

Due to the fact that im using the packages with Octopus Deploy, i would like to avoid these extra folders.

Is it possible to avoid the extra OPC folders without specifying all the replacement tokens on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

What's the names of these extra folders? Please open a new issue/feature request on http://nuget.codeplex.com and describe your issue in more details.